# Python Desktop Application Database

Tags: python, database, python-2.7

Python supports multiple databases

But i want a database for desktop application which could be included in setup of python py2exe

When application pakage is moved then its database also wants to move

example its possible with textfile but i want a database which stores data in table format.

suggest ideas,databases relevance...

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of question does not fit the format of this site, see the [FAQ#dontask]. Questions like these tend to lead to vague answers that are also outdated very quickly. If we can help you with a specific problem, feel free to post another question though!

Comment: That said, Python comes with batteries included, including an embedded database engine. Use the [`sqlite3` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for that.

Answer (score 4):

As Martijn commented, there is the battery included [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module in python which you can use to create and handle file-based sqlite database.

Alternatively you can use third party products like [firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org), which you can embed also in you application.

And if you just only want to store a small number of informations, you can use for example python´s [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html) module or you write/read simple ini-files with the [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html).